# Difference between performance of java 7's asynchronous channels vs nonblocking socket channels

Tags: java, asynchronous, nio

I have once heard that asynchronous socket channels introduced in java7 have far worse performance than nonblocking io using older NIO apis (channels/selectors) on linux.
If that's true, why it is actually the case? I have never done such benchmarking so not quite sure how to check this, and google doesn't find any info about this except one article related to jdk7 that could as well be already outdated.

Comment: There is no reason for any of the three of four APIs to have better or worse performance. They will all be network-bound on transfers of any interesting size. Not CPU-bound. You can't believe everything you read on the Internet.

Comment: I mostly mean usage of these apis for high performance servers. I believe that on high server load it may make difference. THat is mostly what nonblocking nio is used for in socket case.